# how to maintain workflow task list data when retracting or removing workflow association

Tags: 2010, workflow, deployment, workflow-activity, solution-deployment

whenever i try to remove workflow association or retract workflow solution (.wsp) all associated task list data also gets deleted.

i want to prevent this behavior as task list data is important for future use.

Many Thank in Advance.

Comment: Q: do you do retraction by means of Visual Studio by any chance?

Comment: yes WF are created using visual studio, where retract cn be from power shell command or pragmatically disassociating workflow from list..in any case associated task list item gets deleted

Comment: even if the Tasks List is created prior to deploying workflows and only associated with?

Comment: yes..in all cases task list data gets deleted..

Comment: Salman, Did you find any solution to this problem.

Comment: Yes, long time back i wrote an blog post related to it ..please read it http://sharepoint497.blogspot.ae/2012/09/upgrading-or-redeploying-sharepoint.html